# Simple modifications of the default /etc/screenrc

Tags: configuration, default, gnu-screen

One of the first thing I install on a new host is GNU-screen. The next thing right after that is to Google for the lines I need to edit in my `~/.screenrc` to activate the hard-status line so I will see the current active shell sessions.

However since I already have root on my host, I figured it might be faster to edit the default `/etc/screenrc` and I should be able to uncomment a line to have my hard-status line working.

Especially looking at this part, it seems trivial:

```
# An alternative hardstatus to display a bar at the bottom listing the
# windownames and highlighting the current windowname in blue. (This is only
# enabled if there is no hardstatus setting for your terminal)
#
#hardstatus lastline "%-Lw%{= BW}%50>%n%f* %t%{-}%+Lw%<"
```

However no matter what permutation of commenting and uncommenting, and switching `off` settings to `on` and vice versa, I wasn't able to see *any* hard status line.

So **is there a simple modification to the default `/etc/screenrc` that comes with part of the standard Ubuntu package to have a hard-status line that shows the current shells and highlights the current one?**

Answer (score 0):

So I found this line in `/usr/share/doc/screen/examples/screenrc`:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "%Lw"
```

So the answer is to uncomment the line mentioned in the question, but also add `always` before `lastline` giving:

```
hardstatus alwayslastline "%-Lw%{= BW}%50>%n%f* %t%{-}%+Lw%<"
```